# MVC 3 Access page with allow anonymous

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, forms-authentication, global-asax

i'm create a project using mvc 3 with windows authentication. my case is when in login page i'm create a link to redirect page to page "forgot password".
but, the problem is. when i'm click a link to access another page without login. in my url browser show the url like this : "http://localhost:5074/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fForgotPassword".
cannot redirect to controller "forgotpassword".

-I've tried some ways like custom web.config, global.asax and others but it did not work

please correct my code and give me the solution.

View -> login.cshtml

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ForgotPassword")">Forgot Password?</a>
```

Controller -> ForgotPassword

```
namespace EDIS.Controllers
{
public class ForgotPasswordController : MyController
{ 
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
}
```

web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

global.asax

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute()); 
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DevExpressHelper.Theme = "DevEx";
    }

    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            string encTicket = authCookie.Value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(encTicket))
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(encTicket);
                CustomIdentity id = new CustomIdentity(ticket);
                CustomPrincipal principal = new CustomPrincipal(id);
                HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding your question but how about allowing anonymous users to access the ForgotPassword functions within the controller.

```
[AllowAnonymous]  //...or you could move this attribute above Index()
namespace EDIS.Controllers
{
    public class ForgotPasswordController : MyController
    { 
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in mvc 3, [AllowAnonymous] nothing... =(

Comment: Are you authenticating your application with Domain controller, or some other method?